renewcommand{\dot}[1]{} does not work because of fontspec package
Solved. See Answer.

I would like to replace the default symbols of \dot{} and \ddot{} with the ones shown in How to make a larger "\dot" while the commands remain the same.
I've tried the following preamble
\usepackage{accents}
\renewcommand{\dot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\ddot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}

but \dot{x} in text still gives the default result.
Then I tried as follows (ref: How to redefine \times such that it shows dot (from \cdot) instead?)
\let\olddot\dot
\let\oldddot\ddot

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\dt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}

\let\dot\dt
\let\ddot\ddt

However, \dot{x} in text still gives the default one.
Could anyone help? Or is there something I missed?
Thanks.

[Edited]
Thanks to @user202729's advice, I find that it is fontspec's thing --- an unexpected cause of the issue.
Thanks to @MadyYuvi, @campa, and @David Carlisle for reminding me that I didn't offer the minimal working example --- it is my bad ; now it is shown as follows.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{accents}
\renewcommand{\dot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\ddot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\(\dot{x}\)
\end{document}

I have no idea how to resolve this after looking through the documentation of fontspec. Could any one help?
Thanks.

Please post the MWE from \documentclass to \end{document}

Works for me. Whatever is going on is due to code you are withholding. Please provide a full minimal working example which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Your code works fine, hope you are not convinced with the output, so better to increase the size from \large to \Huge and check

Maybe \usepackage{unicode-math} interfere, try moving the set of commands to after \begin{document}?

You need to show an example of the problem, posting fragments does not allow anyone to test (other than a possible guess that you are using unicode-math)

@HRC move the redefinitions after \begin{document}

You can move the definitions as suggested above by using \AtBeginDocument.

Please post your solutions in the answer field below instead of editing them into the question.

Thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and @schtandard, finally the following codes works.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\usepackage{accents}  % use package in \AtBeginDocument
\renewcommand*{\dot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\ddot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\(\dot{x}\)
\end{document}

or
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{accents}  % use package out of \AtBeginDocument

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*{\dot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\ddot}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\(\dot{x}\)
\end{document}

